# Proving differentiability without using limit definition

Tags: real-analysis

**Question:**

Let $f:(-2,2) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the function given by
\begin{equation}f(x)=\begin{cases} \sqrt{4-x^2}, & x \in (-2,0] \\ 2 & x \in (0,2) \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Prove that $f$ is differentiable on $(-2,2)$ and compute $f'(x)$ for each $x \in(-2,2)$.

**Attempt:**

Can I simply say in the first domain, $\sqrt{4-x^2}$ is a differentiable/continuous function so we can use chain rule to find the derivative at this domain??

And $2$ is a differentiable function any domain so we can just differentiate this to get $0$.

I find this question strange because it seems like you dont need to use the differentiable definition limit. Please can someone advise me.

Comment: @x=0 the function changes so you need to check the differentiability at that point. using limit definition.

Comment: You need to differentiate each part and show that derivatives are equal.

Comment: I agree. The limit definition is necessary.

Comment: The limit definition is absolutely necessary. You can't just differentiate each side and check if the result is equal. There are cases where you can differentiate both sides, the derivatives are equal, but the function isn't even continuous.

Comment: Would your way make you to conclude that $f(x) = \begin{cases} x, &x \in (-2, 0) \\ x + 1, & x\in [0, 2)\end{cases}$ is differentiable at $x = 0$? If so, is that a good thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the usual rules for the derivative except at $0$, because in a suitable neighborhood of any point in $(-2,2)$ (except $0$), the function coincides with a function that is known to be differentiable.

At $0$ the situation is different, because we cannot say the function coincides with a function that is known to be differentiable in *any* neighborhood of $0$.

So you *have* to compute
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}
$$
for deciding whether $f$ is differentiable at $0$; in this particular case, you'll do separately the limits from the right and from the left.

One can also use a different limit, but one is necessary anyway. Here's an example.

Since $\lim_{x\to0-}f(x)=2=\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)$, it's meaningful to ask oneself whether the function is differentiable at $0$. In order to do this we can use l'Hôpital's theorem.

Indeed, since we know the function is continuous at $0$, l'Hôpital's theorem says that *if*
$$
\lim_{x\to0}f'(x)
$$
exists, then this limit is equal to
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}
$$
because the derivative of the numerator and the denominator exist in a neighborhood of $0$ (excluding $0$) and both the numerator and the denominator have limit $0$ at $0$.

With the given function we have
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}f'(x)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-x}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}=0,
\qquad
\lim_{x\to0^-}f'(x)=\lim_{x\to0}0=0,
$$
so we can conclude that $f'(0)=0$.

---

Be careful in applying this:

1. continuity at $a$ is *necessary* for the existence of the derivative at $a$;
2. granted continuity at $a$, the existence of the limit of the derivative at $a$ is *sufficient* for the existence of the derivative at $a$.

The classical example is
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
x^2\sin\dfrac{1}{x} & \text{for $x\ne0$}\\[3px]
0 & \text{for $x=0$}
\end{cases}
$$
This function is continuous at $0$ because it's even differentiable:
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to0}x\sin\frac{1}{x}=0.
$$
However
$$
\lim_{x\to0}f'(x)=
\lim_{x\to0}\left(2x\sin\frac{1}{x}-\cos\frac{1}{x}\right)
$$
doesn't exist.

There's nothing really strange here: the derivative $f'$ is everywhere defined, but it happens to not be continuous at $0$.

Answer (score 2):

We do (sort of) need the definition of derivative to deal with differentiability at  at $x=0$.  So we want to show that 
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}$$
exists.
It is clear that the limit above exists and is equal to $0$, if $h$ approaches $0$ from the **right** So it remains to show that 
$$\frac{\sqrt{4-h^2}-2}{h}\to 0$$
as $h$ approaches $0$ from the **left**. To show that this is the case, multiply top and bottom by $\sqrt{4-h^2}+2$.

Answer (score 0):

You have that: $$f'(0^{+}) = \displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = \displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \dfrac{2-2}{x} = 0 $$, and $$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^{-}} \dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}= \displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^{-}} \dfrac{\sqrt{4-x^2}-2}{x}=\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^{-}} \dfrac{-x}{\sqrt{4-x^2}+2}=0=f'(0^{-})\Rightarrow f'(0) = 0$$. Thus $f$ is differentiable at $x= 0$.